# Wrong autoparsed time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

In my application I've got

```
config.time_zone = 'Europe/Prague'
```

in view where the time origins I've got

```
<%= f.input :end_at, as: :string %> <!-- shortened -->
```

This generates strings like 12:31, 05:59, etc. When Time object is created as attribute of Slot model it get's wrong timezone. Being generated like

```
slot = Slot.new({end_at: params[:end_at]})
```

Where model is something like this

```
create_table :slots do |t|
  t.time :end_at
end
```

Then when I try

```
slot.end_at.zone
```

it returns "UTC" so either I don't understand the time concept in rails or there is something wrong. Shouldn't it be "CEST"? From what I got, UTC is used only in database and when you get it out of there it is converted to local time, also Time objects are created in local time. This fails here and saves CEST time to database as UTC leading to wrong times.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try to set your timezone to `Prague` instead of `Europe/Prague`.

Comment: Didn't help. Still the same

Comment: What time is being displayed when you use a [`I18n.l`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) helper?

Comment: well it returns a time, but would it return a date too?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4augiEWR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3145) in Rails. I myself actually see this as the expected behavior as the `time` column has - by definition - no date information in it. So `'10:00'` might be 10AM CEST when saved in the summer in Prague but a completely different time when saved some other time in the year in some other timezone - but in the db it's always just 10AM. Imagine opening a 6 months old record with such time and re-saving it again - this would change the value in the db which seems weird to me.

Anyway, you can simply force Rails to recognize the time as a time of "today" when saving it:

```
slot = Slot.new({end_at: Time.parse(params[:end_at])})
```

This will correctly parse the time as today's time in the configured time zone and save its representation converted to UTC to the db.